# unique pointer of base class with derived member

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

For my C++ program I have a lot of classes where a member should be of one of two types which have the same base class.

I thought I could implement this with pointers but I don't get it to work.

Example: lets assume we have a class A with a member b_ of class B:

```
class A{
public:
    A(B b): b_{b} {}
private:
    B b_;
}
```

The class B has only one function which is pure virtual:

```
class B{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
}
```

now I have two derived classes of B and I want to change A in a way, that it could hold eihther objects of class B1 or B2:

```
class B1: public B{
public:
    void print(){cout << "B1\n";}
}    

class B2: public B{
public:
    void print(){cout << "B2\n";}
}
```

My plan was to use unique pointers:

```
class A{
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b): b_{std::move(b)} {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
}

int main(){

std::unique_ptr<B> b;
if (some condition){
    b = make_unique<B1>(new B1()) ///?
}else{
    b = make_unique<B2>(new B2()) ///?
}
A(b);
A.getB()->print();
}
```

Comment: `b = make_unique<B1>(new B1())`??? ... **Did you mean** `b = make_unique<B1>()`?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes on your code. First of, you can't have two definitions of `A`. Second, you must pass the `unique_ptr` as r-value reference (`std::move`) since it is not copyable. Last, make a variable of type `A` (`a`) and then call methods on it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual ~B() {};
};

class B1: public B{
public:
    void print(){cout << "B1\n";}
};

class B2: public B{
public:
    void print(){cout << "B2\n";}
};

class A{
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<B> b): b_{std::move(b)} {}
    auto *getB() { return b_.get(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
    if(false)
        b = make_unique<B1>();
    else
        b = make_unique<B2>();

    A a(std::move(b));
    a.getB()->print();
}
```